# How to programmatically get all running jobs in a Hadoop cluster using the new API?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a software component which submits MR jobs to Hadoop. I now want to check if there are other jobs running before submitting it. I found out that there is a `Cluster` object in the new API which can be used to query the cluster for running jobs, get their configurations and extract the relevant information from them. However I am having problems using this.

Just doing `new Cluster(conf)` where `conf` is a valid `Configuration` which can be used to access this cluster (e.g., to submit jobs to it) leaves the object unconfigured, and the `getAllJobStatuses()` method of `Cluster` returns `null`.

Extracting `mapreduce.jobtracker.address` from the configuration, constructing an `InetSocketAddress` from it and using the other constructor of `Cluster` throws `Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.`.

Using the old api, doing something like `new JobClient(conf).getAllJobs()` throws an NPE.

What am I missing here? How can I programmatically get the running jobs?

Comment: So do you run Hadoop 2.x? What did you define for `mapreduce.framework.name`?

Comment: Yes, I run Hadoop 2.x. When I set `yarn` for `mapreduce.framework.name` and add the `jobclient` dependency, I get a little further - `new Cluster(...)` runs without error, but `getAllJobStatuses()` hangs. I think the problem might be the mini cluster I use for my integration tests, I have to check running this against a "real" cluster.

Comment: I would assume so, I'm fairly sure it works running against a real cluster ;)

Comment: I investigated some more, and I am pretty sure it is because of the mini cluster. I submitted a dummy job to it (empty input and output directory, nothing else), called `job.getCluster().getAllJobStatuses()` and received `null` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated even more, and I solved it. Thomas Jungblut was right, it was because of the mini cluster. I used the mini cluster following [this blog post](http://www.lopakalogic.com/articles/hadoop-articles/hadoop-testing-with-minicluster/) which turned out to work for MR jobs, but set up the mini cluster in a deprecated way with an incomplete configuration. The Hadoop Wiki has [a page on how to develop unit tests](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToDevelopUnitTests) which also explains how to correctly set up a mini cluster.

Essentially, I do the mini cluster setup the following way:

```
// Create a YarnConfiguration for bootstrapping the minicluster
final YarnConfiguration bootConf = new YarnConfiguration();
// Base directory to store HDFS data in
final File hdfsBase = Files.createTempDirectory("temp-hdfs-").toFile();
bootConf.set(MiniDFSCluster.HDFS_MINIDFS_BASEDIR, hdfsBase.getAbsolutePath());
// Start Mini DFS cluster
final MiniDFSCluster hdfsCluster = new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(bootConf).build();
// Configure and start Mini MR YARN cluster
bootConf.setInt(YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB, 64);
bootConf.setClass(YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER, FifoScheduler.class, ResourceScheduler.class);
final MiniMRYarnCluster yarnCluster = new MiniMRYarnCluster("test-cluster", 1);
yarnCluster.init(bootConf);
yarnCluster.start();
// Get the "real" Configuration to use from now on
final Configuration conf = yarnCluster.getConfig();
// Get the filesystem
final FileSystem fs = new Path ("hdfs://localhost:" + hdfsCluster.getNameNodePort() + "/").getFileSystem(conf);
```

Now, I have `conf` and `fs` I can use to submit jobs and access HDFS, and `new Cluster(conf)` and `cluster.getAllJobStatuses` works as expected.

When everything is done, to shut down and clean up, I call:

```
yarnCluster.stop();
hdfsCluster.shutdown();
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(hdfsBase); // from Apache Commons IO
```

**Note:** `JAVA_HOME` **must** be set for this to work. When building on Jenkins, make sure `JAVA_HOME` is set for the default JDK. Alternatively you can explicitly state a JDK to use, Jenkins will then set up `JAVA_HOME` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it like this, it worked for me, but it is after submitting the job

```
JobClient jc = new JobClient(job.getConfiguration());

  for(JobStatus js: jc.getAllJobs())
  {
    if(js.getState().getValue() == State.RUNNING.getValue())
    {

    }
  }

  jc.close();
```

or else we can get the cluster from job api and there are methods which return all the jobs, jobs status

```
cluster.getAllJobStatuses();
```